# Android - Using Google Maps API - Is it possible to link some sort of google navigation service to any polylines?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to the Google Maps API for android, and recently encountered a problem with a project I'm making. I'm trying to make a network of polylines that represent walking paths on Google maps, but I was wondering, is it possible to get the typical google directions for navigating those polylines? For example, if you are in a park and there are several paths to get to the parking lot, would google maps be able to tell you the fastest path if the paths are represented by polylines?

Comment: Paths in a park might not be available. Anything available would be part of the directions api. Responses include polylines and distance. If you want to use it within Android, you'll probably have to create http requests with it to hit the api.

Comment: @Andy So I can only give navigation/directions for paths that have been added to the Directions API? I guess that would mean I cannot add my own paths to the map to get directions with...

Comment: If you have the coordinates for it, you can draw a polyline with those. However, if you want to navigate through that path, and the route doesn't exist in Google Maps, I'm sure it's doable, but probably much more difficult.